# Does the OpenCV library have speckleFilter function for GPU?

Tags: opencv, gpu

I know there is a CPU version of the OpenCV filterSpeckle function [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/calib3d/src/stereosgbm.cpp#L2343), but is there a GPU version? I haven't found one, but if it in fact doesn't exist, why so?

Have I understand it right, that it is not parallelizable, since its operations depend on the previous iterations?